# Proper way to update (update fallback) a list of entities with child entities?

Tags: c#, ef-core-2.2

I'm building a .net core 2 api with EF core . 
the api gets a list (3K-5K) of entities(DTOs) to sync using a general syncItems function.

assume the following entities :

```
       public class supplier
{
    [Key]
    public string supplierCode { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }
}

 public class item 
{
    public const int maxItemName = 256;
    public const int maxItemCode = 256;
    public const int maxBarcode = 256;
    [Required]
    [StringLength(maxItemName)]
    public string itemName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(maxItemCode)]
    [Key]
    public string sku { get; set; }

    public supplier supplier { get; set; }


    public ICollection<itemWarehouse> whslines = new List<itemWarehouse>();

    public item()
    {

    }
}


my sync does the following : 

var itemsInApp=_appDbContext.items.ToList();
        // insert or update items.
        items.ForEach(erpitem =>
        {
            bool newflag = false;
            item tempItem = itemsInApp.Where(x => x.sku == erpitem.sku).FirstOrDefault();
            if (tempItem==null) // check if item is null
            {
                tempItem = new item();
                tempItem.sku = erpitem.sku;
                newflag = true;
            }
            tempItem.itemName = erpitem.itemName;
            var sup = _appDbContext.suppliers.SingleOrDefault(su=>su.supplierCode==erpitem.supplierCode);
            if (sup == null)
            {
                sup = new supplier { supplierCode = erpitem.supplierCode, name = erpitem.supplierName };
            }
            tempItem.supplier = sup;
            if (newflag)
                _appDbContext.items.AddAsync(tempItem);
        });
        if (_appDbContext.ChangeTracker.HasChanges())
            await _appDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

This runs very slow, and sometimes even hangs (?) 
(due to the supplier) 
I can extract the suppliers from the incoming list and add them before looping over the list of items , hence the supplier code will always exist in the db. 
I'm just not sure if thats the proper way to do it (?) 
most of the online examples tackle updating/inserting a single item.

Any insight / help is much appreciated.

Comment: Why it hangs requires more investigations...but for the slowly there is no silver bullet. All ORMs are powerfull in many scenario, but not in "bulk" operation: if you have to insert/update a group of hundreds entities, you have two way to do this. The first is what you did, and you have to wait. The second is "don't use orm". Write your business operation method with a sql statement with high performance to be fast.

Comment: thanks for the comment , I'm rather new to EF and I was under the impression that I'm doing something wrong if it takes such a long time.

Comment: Check which lines of codes require more exeucution time...I bet is the _appDbContext.SaveChangesAsync(); who takes all the time

Comment: actually like I wrote if I comment these lines
 
var sup = _appDbContext.suppliers.SingleOrDefault(su=>su.supplierCode==erpitem.supplierCode);
            if (sup == null)
            {
                sup = new supplier { supplierCode = erpitem.supplierCode, name = erpitem.supplierName };
            }
            tempItem.supplier = sup;
it works really fast. it's due to the child entitty

Comment: Of course, if you remove many entities he does its work fast